# Setting Active Directory user account for first time

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using the code below to create a new active directory user. The account is created successfully, but when i try to login to my domain i get the message "make sure you entered the password for your work or school account". I made sure that the password is entered correctly and that the account is enabled and unlocked in the active directory.

```
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(createLdapPath);
        try
        {

            DirectoryEntry newUser = entry.Children.Add("CN = " + userName, "USER");
            newUser.Properties["targetAddress"].Value = "SMTP:" + userName + "@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com";
            newUser.Properties["extensionAttribute15"].Value = "EDU";
            newUser.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add("SMTP:" + userName + "@mydomain1.edu");
            newUser.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add("smtp:" + userName + "@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com");
            newUser.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add("smtp:" + userName + "@mydomain2.mail.onmicrosoft.com");
            newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = fname;
            newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lname;
            newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = fname + " " + lname;
            newUser.Properties["mail"].Value = fname.ToLower() + "." + lname.ToLower() + "@mydomain.edu";
            newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = fname.ToLower() + "." + lname.ToLower();
            newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Insert(0, fname.ToLower() + "." + lname.ToLower() + "@mydomain.edu");

            newUser.CommitChanges();

            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "myStrongPassword" });
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            newUser.Close();

            string strUserName = userName;
            DirectoryEntry usr = entry;
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(usr);
            searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + strUserName + ")";
            searcher.CacheResults = false;
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            usr = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            usr.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0;

            int old_UAC = (int)usr.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];

            // AD user account disable flag
            int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2;

            // To enable an ad user account, we need to clear the disable bit/flag:
            usr.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] = (old_UAC & ~ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE);
            usr.CommitChanges();

            usr.Close();
            entry.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

I can only login when i open "Active Directory users and Computers" and navigate to my newly created account--> Right Click--> Reset Password. Then enter the password again and also check on "Unlock user". This way when i try to login again it works fine.

What could I possibly be missing or mistaken in in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to close the 'newUser' object and rebind. Here is my code that is running in our production environment:

```
//Create user
newUser.CommitChanges();

newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 512;
newUser.CommitChanges();
newUser.Close();
```

It's also possible that "(old_UAC & ~ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE)" doesn't turn out to be 512 (ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case it turned out that the active directory hasn't synced yet with office 365.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Active Directory synced hasn't run yet with Office 365 and that's why i couldn't login with the user account. I could sync manually by running Task Scheduler Active Directory sync task.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.